# RQ Timeout does not kill multi-threaded jobs

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-rq, django-rq

I'm having problems running multithreaded tasks using python RQ (tested on v0.5.6 and v0.6.0).

Consider the following piece of code, as a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

## thing.py

```
from threading import Thread

class MyThing(object):
    def say_hello(self):
        while True:
            print "Hello World"

    def hello_task(self):
        t = Thread(target=self.say_hello)
        t.daemon = True # seems like it makes no difference
        t.start()
        t.join()
```

## main.py

```
from rq import Queue
from redis import Redis
from thing import MyThing

conn = Redis()

q = Queue(connection=conn)

q.enqueue(MyThing().say_hello, timeout=5)
```

When executing `main.py` (while rqworker is running in background), the job breaks as expected by timeout, within 5 seconds.

Problem is, when I'm setting a task containing thread/s such as `MyThing().hello_task`, the thread runs forever and nothing happens when the 5 seconds timeout is over.

How can I run a multithreaded task with RQ, such that the timeout will kill the task, its sons, grandsons and their wives?

Comment: Sounds like an good question to post as an rq issue: https://github.com/nvie/rq/issues

Comment: Wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `t.join()`, the `hello_task` thread blocks and waits until the `say_hello` thread returns - thus not receiving the timeout signal from rq. You can allow the main thread to run and properly receive the timeout signal by using `Thread.join` with a set amount of time to wait, while waiting for the thread to finish running. Like so:

```
def hello_task(self):
    t = Thread(target=self.say_hello)
    t.start()
    while t.isAlive():
        t.join(1)  # Block for 1 second
```

That way you could also catch the timeout exception and handle it, if you wish:

```
def hello_task(self):
    t = Thread(target=self.say_hello)
    t.start()
    try:
        while t.isAlive():
            t.join(1)  # Block for 1 second
    except JobTimeoutException:  # From rq.timeouts.JobTimeoutException
        print "Thread killed due to timeout"
        raise
```